# bash: in a case statement, go to other case

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script where I manipulate variables using options, but there are shortcuts if no option is specified.  so for example, I have `add`, `show`, `set`, and `delete`, but if I don't specify any of those, then the input is interpreted to determine which operation to perform:

- `script key` is a shortcut for `script show key`
- `script key=value` is a shortcut for `script set key=value`

I'm written a `case` statement for the options, but in the catchall, is it possible to say "go to case X"?:

```
case $1 in
    add)
        #blah;;
    show)
        #blah;;
    set)
        #blah;;
    delete)
        #blah;;
    *)
        if [[ $1 == *=* ]]; then
            #go to case "set"
        elif [[ $1 ]]; then
            ##go to case "show"
        else
            echo "FAILURE!!!"
            exit 1
        fi
    esac
```

**EDIT**

I came up with:

```
case $1 in
    add)
        #blah;;
    delete)
        #blah;;
    set|*=*)
        #blah;;
    show|*)
        #blah;;
    esac
```

Which almost works, but now if there is no last argument (i.e. i just execute `script`) it will try to run `script show`.

Comment: Sorry I don't see your upate :-)

Comment: `*` matches the empty string; `?*` would not.

Comment: so if I change the case to `show|?*)` i can keep it as a single `case` statement with the standard `*)` catchall? i.e. [this](http://pastebin.com/jKXDzu1s)

Comment: It should. I'm not entirely keen on the shortcut, though. What if you have a key *named* `show`?

Comment: That would be the same problem as if I have a keyword names `add`, `delete`, or `set`.  In those 3 cases, the user will have to use `script show [key]` and the `show` shortcut will be invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest structuring your code like this:

```
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "FAILURE!!!"
    exit 1
fi

case $1 in
    add)
        #blah;;
    set|*=*)
        #blah;;
    delete)
        #blah;;
    show|*)
        #blah;;
esac
```

i.e. fail before hitting the `case` statement and use `|` to combine the patterns for each case.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  out of curiosity, though, is there a difference between `if [[ -z $1 ]]` and `if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]`?

Comment: `$1` could explictly be the empty string: `somecommand "" a b c d e f g h i`. Here, `$1` is empty, but `$#` is much greater than 2.

Comment: @ewok what chepner said! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"${1?arg needed}"` instead of `$1` at the start of `case` to fail the script when `$1` is not supplied.

```
case "${1?arg needed}" in
   add)
      echo "add";;
   delete)
      echo "delete";;
   set|*=*)
      echo "set";;
   show|*)
      echo "show";;
esac
```

Testing this:

```
bash ./script
-bash: 1: arg needed

bash ./script foobar
show

bash ./script abc=123
set
```

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
case $1 in
    add)
        #blah;;
    show|*)
        #blah;;
    set|*=*)
        #blah;;
    delete)
        #blah;;
    *)
        echo "FAILURE!!!"
        exit 1
    esac
```

Comment: Any `$1` value other than `add` will enter your `show|*)` branch; in other words: all remaining branches are never reached.